# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined at XMLHttpRequest.alertContents

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estou fazendo um requisição AJAX, via GET e colocando na variável `httpRequest` e estou tentando usar um `.split(';')` na resposta de texto este é um trecho do código que estou usando:

```
 var prof1 = 0, prof2 = 0,prof3 = 0, prof4 = 0,prof5 = 0, prof6 = 0,prof7 = 0, prof8 = 0,prof9 = 0, prof10 = 0,prof11 = 0, mat1 = 0,mat2 = 0, mat3 = 0, mat4 = 0,mat5 = 0, mat6 = 0, mat7 = 0,mat8 = 0, mat9 = 0, mat10 = 0,mat11 = 0;
    var requestant, requestatual,prof,mat;
    requestant = '';
    window.setInterval(makeRequest, 10000);
    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    function makeRequest() {
        httpRequest.open('GET', 'result.php');
        httpRequest.send();
        if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
            httpRequest.onreadystatechange = alertContents;
        }
    }
    function alertContents() {
        if (requestant !== requestatual) {
            if (requestatual !== '') {
                if (requestatual !== undefined) {
                    requestatual = httpRequest.responseText;
                    requestatual = requestatual.split(';');
                    prof = requestatual[0].split(',');
                    mat = requestatual[1].split(',');
                    prof1 = prof[0];
                    prof2 = prof[1];
                    prof3 = prof[2];
                    prof4 = prof[3];
                    prof5 = prof[4];
                    prof6 = prof[5];
                    prof7 = prof[6];
                    prof8 = prof[7];
                    prof9 = prof[8];
                    prof10 = prof[9];
                    prof11 = prof[10];
                    mat1 = mat[0];
                    mat2 = mat[1];
                    mat3 = mat[2];
                    mat4 = mat[3];
                    mat5 = mat[4];
                    mat6 = mat[5];
                    mat7 = mat[6];
                    mat8 = mat[7];
                    mat9 = mat[8];
                    mat10 = mat[9];
                    mat11 = mat[10];
                    requestant = requestatual;
                    grafcs();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Erro**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined at XMLHttpRequest.alertContents
```

**Resposta que a result.php dá**

```
1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , ;0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
```

Comment: O que está a obter de `httpRequest.responseText` é `undefined`(indefinido) logo não pode fazer `split`. É melhor colocar o resto do código que está a utilizar para a requisição para se conseguir perceber de onde vem o problema.

Comment: já coloquei o js todo

Comment: Faz um console.log(typeof requestatual) antes do split e conta pra gente o que obteve no console.

Comment: Não falta a verificação do status 200 => `httpRequest.status == 200` ? E porquê as variáveis todas? Não era mais fácil usar diretamente os arrays `prof` e `mat`?

Comment: Não, @Isac, já que o status pode ser 304 (Não modificado)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu código tem problemas no recebimento do `XMLHttpRequest`.

Você está verificando o `readyState` antes de carregar o retorno. O correto seria:

```
function makeRequest() {
        httpRequest.open('GET', 'result.php');
        httpRequest.send();
        httpRequest.onreadystatechange=function(){ //callback quando o retorno estiver pronto
            if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) { //processo concluído
                requestatual = httpRequest.responseText; // atribuo os dados recebidos à variável
                alertContents(); // chamo a função
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Pode ser que:**

- `requestatual` pode não ser uma string
- `requestatual` é undefined
- `httpRequest` não está recebendo informações

**Obs:** Mostre mais código da próxima vez.

Comment: não dei um alert() nele está tudo ok

Comment: @LeoneCerqueira você chamou o `makeRequests()`?

Comment: chamei sim ta la no js

Comment: eu n tou vendo la @LeoneCerqueira

Comment: ah, ja vi tente `setInterval(function() {makeRequest();}, 10000);`

Comment: Tentei, mas não resolveu, porque o problema não está na resposta,nem no loop setInterval e sim no `split`

Comment: @LeoneCerqueira dá um `console.log` no `requestatual`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64991/discussion-between-leone-cerqueira-and-pedro-pinto).